# Помогите исправить ошибку отправки формы через телеграм

Tags: php, telegram

Пытаюсь отправить данные из формы. Выдает ошибку:
Notice: Undefined variable: txt in C:\xampp\htdocs\websites\php\telegram.php on line 17

Warning: fopen(https://...@gmail.com%0A**Сообщение:**  выфвфы%0A): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request in C:\xampp\htdocs\websites\php\telegram.php on line 21
Error

Код:

```html
<?php

$name = $_POST['user_name'];
$phone = $_POST['user_phone'];
$email = $_POST['user_email'];
$message = $_POST['user_message'];
$token = "850809013:AAEHEqVQb9MgTi2cLEBvLYdrvDoBHHn8l6o";
$chat_id = "-376097291";
$arr = array(
  'Имя пользователя: ' => $name,
  'Телефон: ' => $phone,
  'Email: ' => $email,
  'Сообщение: ' => $message,
);

foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
  $txt .= "<b>".$key."</b> ".$value."%0A";
};


$sendToTelegram = fopen("https://api.telegram.org/bot{$token}/sendMessage?chat_id={$chat_id}&parse_mode=charset=utf8={$txt}","r");

if ($sendToTelegram) {
  header('Location: /websites/pages/main.php');
} else {
  echo "Error";
}
?>
```

Comment: перед foreach объявите переменную `$txt = '';`

Comment: Выдало след. ошибку Warning: fopen(https://...@gmail.com%0A<b>Сообщение: </b> выфвфы%0A): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request in C:\xampp\htdocs\websites\php\telegram.php on line 23
Error

Comment: Жалуется на эту строчку: $sendToTelegram = fopen("https://api.telegram.org/bot{$token}/sendMessage?chat_id={$chat_id}&parse_mode=charset=utf8={$txt}","r");

Answer (score 0):

$chat_id должен идти без минуса